# How to search array for product 'item type' and send to sheet with name of the 'Item Type'?

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I'm putting together a Google sheet to assemble custom drone builds from a parts list.
The master parts list and compiler are on the MASTER sheet.
I've got my script to assemble an array of the rows based on item type (alphabetical order).

I want to make it so that on the button press, the script assembles and sorts an array, then copies the rows to their item type page so the compiler can make a dropdown menu (menu part exists and works). Just need to populate the item type pages with the data from the master list.

My idea was to run an if statement e.g if string matches, write array string to empty range on matched sheet. Is this possible or is there a much simpler way to do this?

```
/** @customFunction
What I want the script to do:
Read Column 1 from A26:A100 or lookahead for end of list
If current cell contains Sheet Name, copy row to corresponding sheet.
*/

/** function myFunction() {
Browser.msgBox('You clicked it!');
}
@customFunction
*/ 

/** var PDB = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PDB"); //Target sheet for PDB
var VTX = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("VTX"); //Target sheet for VTX
var FRAME = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FRAME"); //Target sheet for FRAME
var MOTOR = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MOTOR"); //Target sheet for MOTOR
var FPVCAM = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FPVCAM"); //Target sheet for FPVCAM
var AIOFC = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AIO FC"); //Target sheet for AIO FC
var ESC = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ESC"); //Target sheet for ESC
var PROPS = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROPS"); //Target sheet for PROPS

var itemType = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
*/


function sortscript() {
Logger.clear(); 
var app = SpreadsheetApp                                       //selects app
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //selects Spreadsheet and Sheet
var itemListArr = [];

for(var i=27;i<=58;i++){
 var itemListGet = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 7).getValues();   //Create Array of Items and rows
itemListArr.push(itemListGet);
 itemListArr.sort();                                               //Groups by item type alphabetically
}


if(itemListArr.indexOf("PDB") > -1) {
activeSheet.getActiveCell()
Logger.log()                        //Does nothing right now ik
}



}
```

Comment: Copy of Current sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kcnPmAcI2mcvZrnYVTK256HruqE4g6O1yEw2RaB8wFY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The question doesn't include a description of the script and doesn't mention if there is problem with it. By the other hand the code include several commented lines that is not clear it they are related or not to the problem. Please edit your question and follow the recommendations in [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not what you are looking for but I think this is too simple a task to use scripts (unless you plan on adding more automation features).

You can simply go to your individual item sheets and use formulas to filter the range on the master sheet.

For the "PBD" sheet, the formula will look like this:

```
=FILTER(MASTER!A27:G,MASTER!A27:A="PDB")
```

Here's the result.

[image]

On the 'Master' sheet, you can then set data validation to reference column 'B' of the 'PBD' sheet. If you include all rows in column B, your items list will automatically update (for example, if there are more than 2 "PDB" items in the dataset)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!

The future plans for the sheet are to populate the list with a search algorithm to source the necessary data from e-stores, so that the list is completely comprehensive.

Comment: @JonWhite It doesn't make any difference. You can have your search algorithm paste values to the sheet and the formulas will still fire.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question, I assume the following:

- You want to populate different sheets from data of a table.
- You desire to do it based on a column of the table (`ITEM`).

If my assumptions are correct, you can use the following answer to achieve your requests.

#### CODE

```js
function sortScript() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    "{SPREADSHEET ID}");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MASTER");
  var row = 27; // First row of the item table
  do {
    var item = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).getValues();
    var destinySheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(item[0][0]);
    destinySheet.appendRow(item[0]);
    row++;
  } while (sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, 1, 7).getValues()[0][0] != "");
}
```

#### BEHAVIOUR

The code will load the first row of the table, read the first column out of it (column `ITEM`) and append the row in the sheet with the same name. Then it will iterate until no more rows are found.

#### OBSERVATIONS

- On your sample spreadsheet, on the 30<sup>th</sup> row, there are one product which `ITEM` column is `FC`. I have considered that it must be `AIO FC` instead. If that is not correct, you will need to create a `FC` sheet.

#### ALLUSIONS

- [`appendRow(rowContents)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: Calling sheet.getRange() for every single row is extremely inefficient and should be discouraged. Imagine if he had 100 rows or more - that will max out execution quotas in no time.  You can just target the entire range and read values from it - that's 1 call vs 100s.